# How to get hold of a model instance from a model formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a formset from a model that has an ImageField inside it. Now when editing the formset I would like to show the image next to the other fields in the template so the user can see what images they have uploaded.

From what I understand their is no simple way of saying:

```
{% for form in model_formset %}
    {{form.model}}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

or is their?

Comment: Have you tried `{{ form.instance }}`?

Comment: @Davor Lucic that resolved my problem and made the django model from the formset queryable. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MyForm = inlineformset_factory(Foo, Bar)
f = MyForm(instance=Foo.objects.all()[0])
f.instance
```